# My regex match is grabbing extra leading and trailing whitespaces. How can I only capture the phone number?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am using this regex to capture phone numbers from a long string:

`\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*`

test string:

`asdjasjkdh 1 800 555 1234 01/01/2012 asdhajksdh     18005551234 jkas 12/11/2012 hd sample@email.com asdha jksdh asjdhjak +86 800 555 1234 sdkajs test@gmail.com lorem ipsume. I am dotminors.zszsd@gmail.ca 18005551234 SADASDD +1 800 555-1234 SSDA ASASD 1-800-555-1234 1 (800) 555-1234 asdsasdadsadasda sdada 8005551234 x5678 wkadakasd asdjsadksad (800)5551234`

```
" 1 800 555 1234 ",
"     18005551234 ",
" +86 800 555 1234 ",
" 18005551234 ",
" +1 800 555-1234 ",
" 1-800-555-1234 ",
"1 (800) 555-1234 ",
" 8005551234 x5678 ",
" (800)5551234"
```

As you notice, a few of the numbers have spaces in the beginning or at the end. How can I only grab the phone number part without having to do a separate trim afterwards?

**EDIT:** If I remove the `\s*` on both ends, it gives me a few phone numbers missing the last digit. I updated my question with the output:

```
"1 800 555 1234",
"     1800555123",
"+86 800 555 1234",
" 1800555123",
"+1 800 555-1234",
"1-800-555-1234",
"1 (800) 555-1234",
" 8005551234 x5678",
" (800)5551234"
```

As you will notice, the second and fourth phone numbers are missing '4' at the end and still grabs a white space.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried it but it gives me a few phone numbers missing the last digit and still have a white space. I updated my question with the output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay perfect, that works! If you post this as an answer, I will accept it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to removing `\s*` from the beginning and end, also remove the space from the first character set, right after the optional capturing group - instead, put the space *inside* that first capturing group, to ensure that, if the first group doesn't match, the match doesn't start with any spaces:

```
(?:\+?(\d{1,3}) *)?[-.(]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?
               ^^   ^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/gYOLTz/1

Comment: Is there any specific difference between this an the one which Wiktor Stribiżew commented as both seem to work correctly: `(?:\+?(\d{1,3})[-. (]*)?(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?`

Comment: That pattern doesn't match leading `[-.(]`s, when the first group doesn't match, eg in the final phone number in the input, `(800)5551234` (though you'd probably only want `(` to match, if the first group wasn't matched? only allow dashes, periods, and spaces after the first match? https://regex101.com/r/gYOLTz/2)

Comment: ok, yes you are right. So your solution is correct. I will accept yours!

Comment: @PranoyC I'd suggest `(?:\+?(\d{1,3})[ .-]*)?(?:(\d{3})|\((\d{3})\))[-. ]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/9TQ3V8/1)) if you need the pattern to be "more correct". The `-` or `.` - if present - should follow the country code, I believe. And if there is `(`, there must be `)`, and there must not be `)` if there is no `(`. Mind there is another capturing group now to capture area codes inside parentheses and outside them, account for them in your replacement pattern or extraction logic.

Comment: @CertainPerformance actually your solution seems to break for `(613-869-1234)`. It gives the first parenthesis but misses the last one. Wiktor's solution works for it.

Comment: @PranoyC If phone numbers can have leading `(`s that aren't part of the area code, then yeah, you can't match `(` unconditionally, have to alternate instead [`(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))`](https://regex101.com/r/gYOLTz/3)